# Firebase - setting currentUser

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

Assuming that I have a whole user object as a JSON (with its access and refresh tokens) - how can I force `firebase/auth` to accept it as its `currentUser` so it triggers e.g. `onTokenIdChange`?

**EDIT:**
I want to authenticate the user on a website (my app #1), and inform the browser extension (my app #2) if successful. Right now I'm passing the JSON representation of a user returned from the website's `onTokenIdChange` to the extension.

**EDIT2:**
This is the user's JSON I'm referring to:

```
{
    "uid": "some-uid-here",
    "email": "john@example.com",
    "emailVerified": false,
    "isAnonymous": false,
    "providerData": [
        {
            "providerId": "password",
            "uid": "john@example.com",
            "displayName": null,
            "email": "john@example.com",
            "phoneNumber": null,
            "photoURL": null
        }
    ],
    "stsTokenManager": {
        "refreshToken": "my-refresh-token",
        "accessToken": "my-access-token",
        "expirationTime": 1664750677967
    },
    "createdAt": "1664712317951",
    "lastLoginAt": "1664740255685",
    "apiKey": "my-api-key",
    "appName": "[DEFAULT]"
}
```

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to accomplish, nor is it clear what you mean by "whole user object as a JSON".  Please edit the question to explain in more detail what the goal is, and what you have so far that isn't working the way you want.

Comment: @DougStevenson Thank you for such fast response. I updated my question with my scenario. You can call me lazy, as I want to use the website's auth functionality to inform the browser extension about an authenticated user (just so I don't have to build the authentication in the extension itself). This is why I'm wondering if `firebase/auth` makes it possible to use e.g. `accessToken` or `refreshToken` to sign in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing the user profile around is not enough to authenticate a user with. If you want to authenticate the user in a different context, you'll have to pass their credentials around or [mint a custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) for them and [sign them in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#sign_in_using_custom_tokens_on_clients) with that.

Comment: What if I have the `accessToken` and/or `refreshToken`? Can I potentially use `signInWithCredential` – if yes, how (failing on that)? Or how should I use the `updateCurrentUser` method?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood the question, but as far as I know, you have to either

1. Use one of the default signIn methods (like `signInWithEmailAndPassword`), which requires user input; I think you are chasing something different
2. Use the [custom token](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk) approach mentioned by Frank. In that case, your backend application will use the `firebase-admin-sdk` to generate custom tokens for a given user, acording to the business logic you desire. Only after that your frontend application will use the `firebase/auth` lib to run the `signInWithCustomToken`, which will log you in.
   Example: your **app #2** must have a way to communicate with your backend in order to retrieve a custom token for the given user